# No FileSystem for scheme "s3" exception when using spark with mlflow

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, mlflow

we are running a Spark job against our Kubernetes cluster and try to log the model to MLflow. We are running Spark 3.2.1 and MLflow 1.26.1 and we are using the following jars to communicate with s3 `hadoop-aws-3.2.2.jar` and `aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar` and configure our spark-submit job with the following parameters:

```bash
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider \
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem \
  --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload=true \
```

When we try to save our Spark model with `mlflow.spark.log_model()` we are getting the following exception:

```java
22/06/24 13:27:21 ERROR Instrumentation: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3"
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.FileSystemOverwrite.handleOverwrite(ReadWrite.scala:673)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWriter.save(ReadWrite.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelWriter.super$save(Pipeline.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelWriter.$anonfun$save$4(Pipeline.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.MLEvents.withSaveInstanceEvent(events.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.MLEvents.withSaveInstanceEvent$(events.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation.withSaveInstanceEvent(Instrumentation.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelWriter.$anonfun$save$3(Pipeline.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelWriter.$anonfun$save$3$adapted(Pipeline.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.$anonfun$instrumented$1(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelWriter.save(Pipeline.scala:344)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

We tried to start our MLflow server with `-default-artifact-root` set to `s3a://...` but when we run our spark job and we call `mlflow.get_artifact_uri()` (which is also used to construct the upload uri in `mlflow.spark.log_model()`) the result starts with `s3` which probably cause the former mentioned exception.
Since Hadoop dropped support for the `s3://` filesystem does anyone know how to log spark models to s3 using MLflow?

Cheers

Comment: The URI prefix is just a string. You could try copying your current configs for `spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl`, or maybe you can do string replacement on the URI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional to the `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl` config parameter, you can try to also set `spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl` to `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem`